# Find a component which is redered outside the root in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

In my react js application i have the next logic:

1. User click on the button
2. The button click triggers the message opening (as modal window)
   What i want to achieve: 
   I want to test using Enzyme, that the text inside the modal window is there, but the problem is that i can't find the text, because the window is rendered outside the root selector.
    Code example:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);


  const getAlert = (children = 'data') => {
    return (
      <Alert
      elevation={6}
      variant="filled"
      className='test'
      open={open}
    >
      {children}
    </Alert>
    )
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{getAlert('hihi')}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>open alert</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The basic idea is like in the code, user click on the button and  the message appears. Trying to find the alert box: `expect(wrapper.find('.MuiAlert-root')).toHaveLength(1);`, i get that received length: 0, not 1, so my test does not pass.

```js
 const wrapper = mount(
      <Page/>,
    );

wrapper.find('my-id').hostNodes().simulate('click');
expect(wrapper.find('.MuiAlert-root')).toHaveLength(1); // receive 0 not 1
```

Packages:
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.58",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
""react": "^17.0.2",

How to find my open window in the case that i described above? Who faced with the same issue and can help?

Comment: are you using @material-ui/lab? (e.g. "MuiAlert-root"), could you provide more details about the dependencies you are using and their versions?

Comment: Yes, material ui

Comment: @oieduardorabelo, do you have a solution for my case? It will be very helpful

Comment: update your question, mate... add the versions you are using, packages etc... make it clear what you are using, there's no way to guess it

Comment: @oieduardorabelo, i updated the question with packages. Do you know a solution?

Comment: @oieduardorabelo, could you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074451/check-if-the-function-is-triggered-in-reactjs ?