# Check if the function is triggered in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have this component in my react application:

```js
export const DEMO = {
  test: {
    hi: (txt) => console.log(txt)
  }
}

export default function App() {
  
  const getAlert = (c) => {
    DEMO.test.hi('hello');
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={getAlert}>open alert</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Bassicaly when i hit the button i trigger the function which console.log the text.
Also i created a test for this component using enzyme and jest.

```js
it('should trigger calls', () => {
    const spyOnFun = jest.spyOn(DEMO.test, 'hi');

    const wrapper = shallow(
      <App/>,
    );
     wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    
    expect(spyOnFun).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); //expect 1 but get 0
  });
```

How you can see i spy the method `jest.spyOn(DEMO.test, 'hi');` and i expect that after click to get 1 call, but instead i got 0 and my test does not pass. 
 What could be the issue and hoe to solve?

Comment: I haven't used jest before, but shouldn't it be jest.spyOn(DEMO.test.hi, 'hi') ? (You are missing .hi as method name)

Comment: @no, you can check here https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: I tried it locally and the test passed without problems. Can you post your whole test code?

Comment: @Ibsn, i tried to test this logic https://codesandbox.io/s/pk9yb , basically the idea is next, user click on the button and should appear the `This is a normal message` from `message.info('This is a normal message');`. Tryng `const spyOnFun = jest.spyOn(message, 'info');`  i get 0 calls. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

working based on your question, you can use spyOn on the object:

```
// App.js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "antd";

export const DEMO = {
  test: {
    hi: (txt) => console.log(txt)
  }
};

const info = () => {
  DEMO.test.hi("hello");
};

export function App() {
  return (
    <Button type="primary" onClick={info}>
      Display normal message
    </Button>
  );
}
```

and for your tests:

```
// App.test.js
import React from "react";
import { configure, shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import { App, DEMO } from "./App";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

it("should trigger calls", () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(DEMO.test, "hi");
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  wrapper.find("Button").simulate("click");
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

working demo on: https://codesandbox.io/s/enzyme-spy-on-m3s42

as a suggestion, the React community moved away from shallow rendering and you should consider using https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/ in your projects